# Enable text box based on radio button selected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Radio Button List that lists different business categories.  The last option is the `Other` category.  When the user selects the `Other` category, I want to be able to enable a text box that the user can then enter further information to explain the `Other` selection.

Currently, I am attempting

```
    If rblCategory.SelectedIndex = 20 Then
        txtOther.Enabled = True
        lblOther.Text = rblCategory.SelectedItem.Text()
    End If
```

In this excerpt, I am basing it on the index, but I've also tried basing it on the Text field as well as the Value field, but I still have not gotten it to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you step through the debugger?

Comment: Nothing.  Breakpoints don't work either.

Comment: @SouthShoreAK is there something I have to do to 'reload' the form to show the changes?

Comment: If your breakpoints aren't being hit, that is a good clue that something bigger is wrong. Do all of the controls you are working with have ViewStateEnabled=true? For a radio button list, I think you may need to set CausesValidation=true, and also AutoPostBack=true. Some controls do not post back by default and I think that may be one of them.

Comment: reposted as an answer if you want to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your breakpoints aren't being hit, that is a good clue that something bigger is wrong. Do all of the controls you are working with have ViewStateEnabled=true? For a radio button list, I think you may need to set CausesValidation=true, and also AutoPostBack=true. Some controls do not post back by default and I think that may be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably simplify this by simply hooking into the OnCheckChanged event of that last radiobutton.

```
Private Sub OtherRadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OtherRadioButton.CheckedChanged
    Dim r As RadioButton = CType(sender, RadioButton)

    txtOther.Enabled     = r.Checked
    lblOther.Text        = r.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Turns out I didn't have ViewStateEnabled=true, CausesValidation=true, and AutoPostBack=true